# Forcing HTTPS doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, https

I'm trying to force HTTPS through .htaccess and I'm constantly getting an error of too many redirects.

This is my .htaccess file:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^patrickwhitehouse.pw$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://patrickwhitehouse.pw/$1 [L,R=301]

#force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Options +MultiViews




<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^&\ ]+).html
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

RedirectMatch ^/blogs$ http://www.patrickwhitehouse.pw/blog.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first rewrite rule is the culprit, for each successful redirection to `https` it then re-redirects to the hard coded `http` again on the *next* request after the *external* redirection...

Try this slightly modified version instead:

```
RewriteEngine On    

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^patrickwhitehouse.pw$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://patrickwhitehouse.pw/$1 [L,R=301]

#force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Or, a bit cleaned up:

```
RewriteEngine On    

# force host 'patrickwhitehouse.pw'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^patrickwhitehouse.pw$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://patrickwhitehouse.pw%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've just tried your solution and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I suggest you clear your browsers cache or make a deep reload... If the error persists then you either have to enable rewrite logging (find the details in the rewrite modules documentation), it tells you exactly what is going on inside your rewrite engine, or you use a network sniffer to examine the actual redirections getting sent.

Comment: Oh, I just see that you have to adapt this rule `RedirectMatch ^/blogs$ http://www.patrickwhitehouse.pw/blog.html` of yours accordingly to `RedirectRule ^/blogs$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://patrickwhitehouse.pw/blog.html`